# K-Map resulting in a simplified function of 1

Tags: boolean-algebra

I hope the title wasn't butchered but I'll do my best to explain here. I am trying to find the simplified function of $F$ using a K-map and after going through everything I arrived at the simplified function of $F=1$ which doesn't seem right so I wanted to run my work through here and see if there is something I'm missing. below is all my steps

$$F=\overline{ABC}+\overline{A}B+AB\overline{C}+AC$$

which results in the K-map:

[image: Kmap]

I hope the K-Map is clear, the three groups below are:
$$$$
$$=AB\overline{C}+A\overline{B}C$$
$$=A$$

above is the first one, below is the second,

$$\overline{ABC}+\overline{A}BC$$
$$=\overline{A}$$

and below is the third group,

$$=ABC+AB\overline{C}+\overline{A}BC+\overline{A}B\overline{C}$$
$$=AB+\overline{A}B$$
$$=B$$

After all of these I am left with a simplified function of

$$F=A+\overline{A}+B$$
$$F=1+B$$
 since $$A+\overline{A}=1$$
$$F=1$$
since$$ 1+X=1$$

I don't know if this is alright, I hope I was able to get my steps across properly, is it possible to have a simplified function of 1? I know that the original F does not always result in 1, there are cases where F=0, because of that I don't really know what I did wrong.

Comment: It is not true that $\overline{ABC} + \bar ABC = \bar A$.  Rather, we have
$$
\overline{ABC} + \bar ABC = \bar A(\overline{BC} + BC)
$$
which amounts to $A$ and $NXOR(B,C)$

Comment: That is, assuming you've gone with the usual convention and used $\overline{BC}$ to denote (not B) and (not C) rather than not (B and C)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I must admit I've never seen the convention you refer to as the usual convention. In my experience, the usual convention is [this one](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~kauffman/BooleanAlg.pdf).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom well I know that $wy+w\overline{y}=w$ so in this case $w=\overline{A}$ and $y=\overline{BC}$ and $\overline{y}=BC$ making what I did true unless I misunderstood the rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you give an example where $F=0$? As I see it, the function $F$ does reduce to $F=1$ as shown below:

\begin{align}
F & =\overline{ABC}+\overline{A}B+AB\overline{C}+AC \\
 & = \overline{A}+ \overline{B}+ \overline{C}+\overline{A}B+AB\overline{C}+AC \\ 
 & = (\overline{A}+\overline{A}B)+ \overline{B}+ (\overline{C}+AB\overline{C})+AC  \\
 & = \overline{A}+ \overline{B}+ \overline{C}+AC \\ 
 &=(\overline{A}+ \overline{C})+\overline{(\overline{A}+ \overline{C})}+ \overline{B} \\
 &=1+ \overline{B} \\
 &=1
\end{align}
The rules used are De Morgan, commutative, absorption, commutative and De Morgan, complementation and finally annihilator.

**EDIT**

If $\overline{ABC}$ means "Not(A) and Not(B) and Not(C)" (usually written as $\overline{A}\cdot \overline{B}\cdot \overline{C}$) the expression reduces to $$F=B + A\odot C$$
where $\odot$ is the Exclusive NOR.

Comment: Well I drew out the truth table for this question and in the case where $A=0$, $B=0$, and $C=1$ then we have $\overline{ABC}$ evaluate to 0, $\overline{A}B$ is also 0, $AB\overline{C}$ is also 0, and finally, $AC$ is also 0 making F zero, I'm not a hundred percent sure but this means that the simplified F can't be 1 since F can evaluate to 0

Comment: When $A=0$, $B=0$ and $C=1$ then $\overline{ABC}=1$.

Comment: Are you sure about that? $\overline{ABC}$ is supposed to be Not(A) and Not(B) and Not(C), it is not NOT(ABC). When I punch in Not(A) and Not(B) and Not(C) into Wolfram alpha it tells me that the case of A=F, B=F, C=T results in F=F.

Comment: Where did you see that notation? How would you then show Not(A and B and C)?

Comment: I just messed up, I realized after that I was confusing everyone with my notation, sorry about that. Given that I have clarified my notation, does it make more sense now why I was asking if the simplified F was correct when I got 1 for it.